# Android - GridView : Specify Column Span

Tags: android, gridview, html-table

How can you specify a column span in an android's gridview?

I have a gridview that displays 3 images for each row. Sometimes, there are images that have to span 2 rows.

Is it possible to do that in Android?
or should I be using a different view?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`TableLayout` and `GridLayout` support column spanning, but `GridView` does not.

Comment: Actually GridLayout is the one to use for spanning. It's in the Support v7 library, not jar.

Comment: @MinceMan: Note that this answer is from 2009, before the introduction of `GridLayout`.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this library would work for you. https://github.com/felipecsl/AsymmetricGridView

Answer (score 0):

If you still want to use a GridView, you can hide one of the cells and extended the width of the one next to it so it spans the entire width.  This can be done in your RowAdapter.

```
private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;

public class GridRowAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
    private String[] imageURLArray;

    public GridRowAdapter(String[] imageURLArray)
    {
        this.imageURLArray = imageURLArray;

        if(inflater == null)
        {
            inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        }
    }

    public int getCount()
    {
        int iCount = Math.max(imageURLArray.length, 1);

        //Reduce the count of items expected by the GridView because 1 item will take up 2 cells 
        iCount--;

        return iCount;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position)
    {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position)
    {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        View v = convertView;

        try
        {
            if(parent != null)
            {
                if(position < 2)
                {
                    v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_item_feature, parent, false);

                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = v.getLayoutParams();

                    if(position == 0)
                    {
                        //Extend height and width of the cell on the left
                        params.height = (itemsGridView.getWidth());
                        params.width = (itemsGridView.getWidth());

                        //Write code to show Image or Text
                        String strImage = imageURLArray[position];

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //You must extend the height of this cell too even though you're going to make it disappear
                        params.height = (itemsGridView.getWidth());

                        //Hide cell on the right
                        v.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    //Reduce the index of the position because we skipped an item 
                    position--;

                    v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_item, parent, false);

                    //Write code to show Image or Text
                    String strImage = imageURLArray[position];
                }
            }

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return v;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help you:

```
<GridLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:columnCount="3"
    android:rowCount="4"
    android:layout_margin="15dp"
    android:background="#DEB887">

    <Button android:text="Button 1" />
    <Button android:text="Button 2" />
    <Button android:text="Button 3" />
    <Button android:text="Button 4" />
    <Button android:text="Column Span 2"
            android:layout_columnSpan="2"
            />
    <Button android:text="Button 6" />
    <Button android:text="Row Span 2"
            android:layout_rowSpan="2"
            />
    <Button android:text="Button 8" />
    <Button android:text="Button 9" />
    <Button android:text="Button 10" />
    <Button android:text="Button 11" />
    <Button android:text="Button 12" />
    <Button android:text="Button 13" />

</GridLayout>
```

[image: example snapshot]