# Span two columns of gridview over three

Tags: android, gridview

I hope someone can help me, I have a grid layout populated by an adapter with 8 items. There are three columns in the grid, this leaves me with two rows with three full columns and on with two and an empty gap at the end. I have attached images to detail what I'm trying to achieve.  I want to be able to stretch the last row rows columns to fill the width of the gridview. This is being populated by an adapter.

Below is how the app is now, I have content in 8 cells, there is no ninth cell in case there's confusion with my image.
[image: How the application is now]

Here is how I would like it to look.
[image]
So I would like to stretch the two cells across three columns.

Below is my code for what I have implemented so far

```
public class channels_fragment extends Fragment {

    private View view;
    private GridView channelsGridView;
    protected Handler handler;
    //protected GridAdapter gridAdapter;
    private Main_Activity main;
    private final ChannelsModel model = new ChannelsModel();

    static final String[] channelTitles = new String[]{"test1", "test2", "test3", "test4", "test5", "test6", "test7", "test8"};


    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        main = (Main_Activity) this.getActivity();
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.channels_fragment_layout, null);

        channelsGridView = (GridView)view.findViewById(R.id.channelsGrid);

        channelsGridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this.getActivity(), channelTitles));
        channelsGridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            }
        });


        return view;
    }


    public static int convertDpToPixels(float dp, Context context){
        Resources resources = context.getResources();
        return (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(
                TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,
                dp,
                resources.getDisplayMetrics()
        );
    }

class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    private Context context;
    private final String[] channelTitles;

    public ImageAdapter(Context context, String[] channelTitles){
        this.context = context;
        this.channelTitles = channelTitles;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View gridView;

        if (convertView == null) {

            gridView = new View(context);

            // get layout from mobile.xml
            gridView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_item_layout, null);

            // set value into textview
            TextView textView = (TextView) gridView
                    .findViewById(R.id.grid_item_text);
            textView.setText(channelTitles[position]);

            // set image based on selected text
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) gridView
                    .findViewById(R.id.grid_item_image);

            ImageView iv = (ImageView) gridView.findViewById(R.id.ver_border_dark);

            String channelTitle = channelTitles[position];

            if (position == 6 ){

                gridView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background_bottom_dark);
                textView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

            }
            if (position ==7)

            {
                gridView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background_bottom_dark);
                textView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                iv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.grid_line_ondark_vert);
            }

            if (channelTitle.equals("test1")) {
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_events);
            } else if (channelTitle.equals("test2?")) {
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_whats_nearby);
            } else if (channelTitle.equals("test3")) {
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_top_tips);
            } else if (channelTitle.equals("test4")) {
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_plan_my_trip);
            } else if (channelTitle.equals("test5")) {
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_special_offers);
            } else if (channelTitle.equals("test6")) {
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_explore_more);
            } else if (channelTitle.equals("test7")) {
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_city_plus);
            } else if (channelTitle.equals("test8")) {

                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_audio_guides);
            }

        } else {
            gridView = (View) convertView;
        }

        return gridView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return channelTitles.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

}
```

Here is the code for my fragment layout including the gridview

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Relative xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id = "@+id/dub_photo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/photo"/>

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/channelsGrid"
        android:background="@drawable/light_background"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:columnWidth="100dp"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:layout_below="@+id/dub_photo">
    </GridView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

and finally the layout for my grid item

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/gridItem"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:padding="10dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id ="@+id/grid_item_image"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

        <TextView
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:id = "@+id/grid_item_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="12dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/grid_item_image"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/horizontal_border"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/gridItem">

        <ImageView
            android:id = "@+id/hor_border"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/grid_line_horizontal"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignStart="@id/horizontal_border"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/horizontal_border">

        <ImageView
            android:id = "@+id/ver_border"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/grid_line_vertical"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id = "@+id/ver_border_dark"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/grid_line_ondark_vert"
            android:visibility="gone"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

If anyone could help me with this i'd appreciate it greatly.  I have researched the forums and I've come across suggestions of using gridlayout, there are supported from api 14 and up but I'm developing for api 9 and up.

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android - GridView : Specify Column Span](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1272742/android-gridview-specify-column-span)

Comment: it's not a duplicate, how is it a duplicate? I am asking a specific question, I am providing my source..I have also looked at that, in that answer there is no help except to say that a table layout provides spanning

Comment: Asking a new question with the same base doesn't make it different? If its not possible using GridView then you may not try to do it with Gridview !

Comment: It is different as I can't use a table layout, I am parsing xml, and using an adapter to populate my grid.  I don't know if it's possible to do it with a gridview, that is why I ask the question in the hope that someone will provide some helpful information...I have been through stack overflow, I have looked up the relevant questions, the answers that I have found are not useful.  So I needed to ask my question.  Thank you for your help anyway

Comment: @DJ-DOO any luck ? please share

Comment: @AZ_  I had to take a different approach.  I ended up using nested fragments.  So I had a top and bottom fragment, I still used the same data source but I created two sublists in the adapters, one for the 6 item grid in the top fragment and the other with the data for the 2 item grid for the bottom fragment.  The result is exactly as I wanted and works quite well...of course after a lot banging my head against the wall...it's a good solution if you're using fragments

Comment: Please share a sample code. because I am still not sure how two lists scroll. please share code

Comment: I didn't use lists..I used grids...I used nested fragments to display two grids, one with size 6 and one with size 2, like my images above and rather than having one grid with nine and an empty grid...

Answer (score 0):

You could use a RecyclerView with a GridLayoutManager to do the job:

```
    final int columns = 12;
    GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), columns);
    gridLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    gridLayoutManager.setSpanSizeLookup(
            new GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() {
                @Override
                public int getSpanSize(int position) {
                    IItem adapterItem = mAdapter.getItem(position);
                    if (adapterItem instanceof DefaultItem) {
                        return columns/3;
                    }
                    if (adapterItem instanceof BiggerItem) {
                        return columns / 2;
                    }
                    if (adapterItem instanceof FullWidthItem) {
                        return columns;
                    }
                    return 1;
                }
            });

    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);
```

PS: I used the FastAdapter lib to create the items for the RecyclerView, which I can highly recommend: https://github.com/mikepenz/FastAdapter