# Irregular size in gridview

Tags: java, android, android-gridview

Is it possible to get this result using GridView?

[image]

Comment: Yes, use table layout. Its easily achievable

Comment: possible duplicate :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1272742/android-gridview-specify-column-span

Answer (score 2):

These may be helpful to you

[resource 1](https://github.com/maurycyw/StaggeredGridView)

[resource 2](https://github.com/etsy/AndroidStaggeredGrid)